# How to change the background of context menu for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

As you can see on the picture the EditText's context menu and the text selectors have white bg. Do you know how to change it to transparent so it will blend into the screen properly?

[image: Here is picture.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use standard Activity, with `Theme.AppCompat` or

in your theme add this:

```
android:panelBackground=@android:color/transparent
```

Comment: I tried to use this attribute on the EditText but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only transparency you're trying to achieve try this:

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I don't mean the EditText bg but rather the EditText context menu bg.

Comment: The menu with 'Cut, Copy, Paste'?

Comment: Yes, or to be more exact that huge white rectangle around it. I checked other EditTexts s well with layout bounds enabled in dev options and this rectangle is always there but lot of times you can't see it because of the white bg of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing my

```
<item name="android:Background">@color/priDefault</item>
```

into

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/priDefault</item>
```

in my main theme.